# How to specify in the documentation that the param description is the same as another method?

Tags: c#

I have several methods with the same parameters as so:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// abc
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="log">ILogger object to be used to log via stdout.</param>
        /// <param name="abc">Some random string</param>
        public static void abc(ILogger log, string abc)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// pqr
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="log">ILogger object to be used to log via stdout.</param>
        /// <param name="abc">Some random string</param>
        public static void pqr(ILogger log, string abc)
        {
        }
```

How do I specify in the c# method documentation that the parameters in both these methods are the same without having to type the same information in each of them individually? Should I be using the `<see>` tag?

Comment: [<inheritdoc>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#reuse-documentation-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `<see cref=pqr>` or you can do a `<remark>This method is the same as <see cref=pqr></remark>`.  Intellisense will tell you if the `cref` is correct or not.

The key is to make it easier to understand, not to get the correct tag.

It is always better to write "self-documenting code".  For example, pick method names that describe exactly what this method does or even create a `public` method that then calls either of the `private` methods.